# Como usar React.memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

No sé porque, pero un componente ralentiza toda la web. He intentado `React.memo` pero no funciona:

```
 <ResultFind _categorys={categorys} _resultcat={resultcat} />
    <Grid container style={{ marginBottom: '2rem', marginTop: '2rem' }}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
        <ParentCategory _treecategorys={treecategorys} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={9}>
        <ChildCategory _children={children} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Container>
```

.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        initdata();
      }, [categorias]);
    
      const ResultFind = React.memo(({ _categorys, _resultcat }) => {
        return (
          <Box>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={5} md={4}>
                <Autocomplete
                  id='tags-standard'
                  options={_categorys}
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
                  onChange={(e, v) => (v != null ? seleccionados(v) : {})}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      variant='standard'
                      placeholder='Buscar Categoria'
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={7} md={8}>
                <CVInput readOnly={true} value={_resultcat} onChange={() => {}} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        );
      });
```

¿Hay alguna otra forma para evitar que renderize en cada acción?

Comment: ¿De que tipo son las props `_categorys` y  `_resultcat`, son tipo `array`? saludos

Comment: Has probado con useCallback(), si ese componente no tiene que renderizarse cada vez, quizá es buena opción. Y hacer que se renderice al variar los props de _categorys o _resultcat.